# Difference or relation between ADM mass, Brown-York Quasi-local mass, Komar mass

Tags: general-relativity, mass

Can you give me some explanations for difference or relation between ADM mass, Quasi-Local mass and Komar mass?

What i know about is there is some relation between ADM mass and Quasi-local mass. (i.e, in some limit of Quasi-local mass, we can obtain ADM mass)

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_general_relativity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this reference Beig 1978 phys. Lett Ashtekar and Magno Ashtekar 1979. I understand that the Komar mass is defined only for stationary spacetime while ADM you don´t need to have a stationary spacetime, but you need to have an asymptotically behaviour of the metric tensor, i.e. a well defined metric tensor at infinity. So in the case stationary spacetime and asymptotically flat the Komar mass and the ADM mass do coincide. In general the ADM mass is used in an initial value problem (numerical relativity). The quasi-local mass I don´t have information now, but may be latter I will try to read about it. A mathematical expressions for MADM and Mkomar you can see a paper of bonazzola gourgoulho 1993. Good luck for you :) :)